# Error: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item for theorem like environment within the questions environment

Tags: errors, exam, amsthm

I have used the `exam` document class with `amsthm` package.

I have defined `\lemma` as follows -

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

And it has been used as -

```
\begin{questions}

\section*{Multiple Choice Type Questions}

\begin{lemma}
    \label{lem:1}
    Consider a scalar valued function, $f(t): \R \rightarrow \R$. Suppose $f(t)$ is bounded from below and non-increasing. Then, $f(t)$ has a finite limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$.
\end{lemma}

\question What is the finite limit in Lemma \ref{lem:1}?

\begin{choices}
    \choice infinum $f_m$
    \choice supremum $f_s$
    \choice some quantity between $f_m \n f_s$
    \choice None of the above
\end{choices}

\end{questions}
```

I get the following error -

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.27 \begin{lemma}
```

Other similar questions talk about `theorem` like environments in an `enumerate` environment or similar. I know that there is some issue with some counters, but I am unable to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The `exam` document class provides several list-like environments, among them `questions` and `choices` (note the plural form of the nouns). As they are list-like environments, they are "items" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word). But, unlike, say, with the basic `itemize` and `enumerate` environments, where items are initiated with `\item` directives, the `questions` and `choices` environments require `\question` and `\choice` directives (note the singular form).

Now, while LaTeX list-like environments *can* tolerate containing a `\section` directive to start with, they aren't happy if the first piece of "real text" isn't started with an appropriate `\item`, `\question`, or `\choice` directive.

The simplest way to fix your situation is to move the start of the  `questions` environment to *after* the end of the `lemma` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\providecommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section*{Multiple choice questions}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:1}
Consider a scalar function $f(t)\colon \R \rightarrow \R$. 
Suppose $f(t)$ is bounded from below and non-increasing. Then, 
$f(t)$ has a finite limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{questions} % <-- now after the 'lemma' environment.

\question What is the finite limit in Lemma \ref{lem:1}?

\begin{choices}
    \choice infinum $f_m$
    \choice supremum $f_s$
    \choice some quantity between $f_m$ and $f_s$
    \choice none of the above
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is something I have already done to compile the pdf in the meantime. Moreover, I can't split the ```questions``` environment. Now, the issue is that when the questions are spread over, say, 10 pages, searching for lemmas or theorems at the top is difficult. I want a way to put lemmas in the middle which can be referenced when necessary.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I can't split the  `questions` environment." Incidentally, I can't remember suggesting to you to "split the `questions` environment.